# POSTGRES ERROR: could not load library

Tags: postgresql-9.1

I am not able to perform any operation on my database. The error I'm getting is :

"error: could not load library "C:/Program Files/PostGreSQL/9.1/lib/postgis-2.0.dll": Invalid access to memory location."

The error popped up only today morning and it was fine until yesterday.

Thanks in advance for your help. :D

Answer (score 6):

A system restart fixed the thing. :D